# Best way to disable UITextField "up" and "down" arrows

Tags: swift, uikit

My ViewController has two UITextFields, so by default the keyboard toolbar has these `^` and `v` buttons.  I don't want the user to be able to switch between the textfields with these buttons so i'd like to hide them if possible.  I've tried disabling the inactive textfield but this messes with the firstResponder methods so if possible I'd like a different solution.  Is there any way to just hide these buttons from the default toolbar?

[image: keyboardImage]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCbf2.png)

Comment: hi dear friend, could you find any solution for this?

Comment: I didn't find a simple solution, instead I opted to replace the input accessory view with a custom view.

Comment: Thank you Alec. I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set an empty [inputAccessoryView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621119-inputaccessoryview) of this textField. Or simply:

```
myTextView.inputAccessoryView = nil
```

to remove the whole accessoryView.

Comment: Yes that does work unfortunately that also removes the "Done" button as well.  I may just have to make a custom inputAccessoryView.

Answer (score 1):

**The proper way to handle this change with the latest swift5.5+**

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared().previousNextDisplayMode = .alwaysHide
```

Comment: Of course this assumes the OP is using IQKeyboardManager.